# Use local admin or domain admin to raise privileges on a machine for administrative purposes?

Tags: windows, domain-admin

By now I would hope that, unless there were extenuating circumstances, all users (including administrative users) use a low-level account for their daily activities and raise their permissions to perform administrative tasks.

Obviously domain-based tasks need to utilize a domain account, but software & driver installation can be done via local admin.

In thinking in terms of preventing lateral movement through a network, is elevating to a domain or local account the safest option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Risk**

Two attack vectors to keep in mind here:

- If an attacker compromises the Local Admin account and it uses a common password with other systems in the environment -it's a security risk because of credential sharing.
- If a user elevates to a Domain Admin account, his credentials are available in plaintext (during his logged on session) and available in a cached form thereafter. *Note: The cached credentials may or may not be available, but they are enabled by default in Windows and store 10 of the last logged-in users*. So the security risk here is that if DA credentials are compromised the lateral movement involves the **entire** domain.

**Solution**

You know the saying about opinions... *(insert cliché here)*, but here is my recommendation to clients.

- Randomize the local admin password for all systems in the domain (research Microsoft LAPS for more info), and even systems *not* in the domain.
- Use the local admin for system-level changes (patching, updating, installing, etc)
- Set Domain Admin accounts to **only be able to logon to Domain Controllers** to reduce the risk of leaving credentials in the environment.
- Optionally, create a "Power IT User" for admin tasks on servers within the environment that **is not** a domain admin, if users balk about needing to login as a local admin every time. *Be sure to disable cached credentials, and make sure users logoff when finished.*